# CSP Error while uploading to S3 Bucket using Pre-signed URL from my web application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to upload one document to **AWS S3** Bucket using a presigned url from my **React Js** application.

I have added the following **CORS** policy to the respective bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000",
            "https://portal.myapp.com",
            "https://portal.*.myapp.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Post this change, it started working from my localhost. Before that it wasn't uploading from localhost also.

Now, the issue is that, post deployment of the web application to AWS, I am not able to upload the file.

I have tried the following steps:

Added `"Content-Security-Policy": "connect-src 'self' http://my-bucket-dev.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"` to make sure that CSP is set properly. [REF [link](https://medium.com/swlh/content-security-policy-what-you-need-to-know-ffbce22336d6)]

Didn't work. Same CSP error.

As a next step I have added **Origin** to my request header:
`"Origin": "https://portal.dev.myapp.com"` [REF [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors-troubleshooting.html)]

This is also not helping. Getting the same '**blocked:csp**' error.

Any idea on what is going wrong here?

Comment: did you solve the problem? You are missing https BTW in connect-src http://my-bucket-dev.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/